# How to send id with <a href > of an element in struts jQuery grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I want to retrieve and send an id of an element in struts jQuery grid.

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable"
        caption="Editer Eleves"
        dataType="json"
        width="755"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="5,10,15,20"
        rowNum="5"
        rownumbers="true"
        multiselect="true"      

    >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId" title="Eleve Id" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveNom" index="eleveNom" title="Eleve Nom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="elevePrenom" index="elevePrenom" title="Eleve Prenom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>

</sjg:grid>
```

so I did these but it's not working:

```
<p><a class="btn" onclick="jQuery('#gridtable').getRowData(id)['eleveId']" href="#"> Détails</a>
```

Comment: Where exist `<a class="btn" ...>` element? Do you include such buttons in some column of the grid using custom formatter?. It's unclear what you do now and what you need?

Comment: @Oleg:hi,thanks for replay,what i want is when a row is selected,i want to pass eleveID to a struts2 action.realy my code is not pretty but i don't know how to proced!

Comment: If row is selected then `onSelectRow` callback will be called. One get the rowid as the first parameter. The callback is JavaScript function. Why you need call some action on the server side? Do you have more as one grids on the page (like master/details grids)?

Comment: @Oleg:what i want  is to retrieve eleveId for showing more details in another jsp,i did these in javascript but when i select a column it shows false <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $.subscribe('myTableRowSelected', function(event,data) { 
             var grid = event.originalEvent.grid; 
             var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); 
             var EleveId = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'EleveId'); 
             alert(EleveId); 
            }); 
});

Comment: Sorry but the code which you posted is wrong. Why you use `myTableRowSelected` fantasy event? I'm not struts2 developer. Look at [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Topics). You should use `onSelectRowTopics` (see [the example](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Example)) or use directly `jqGridSelectRow` event provided by jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2))

Comment: @Oleg,in my grid, i did these onSelectRowTopics="myTableRowSelected",so in my javascript $.subscribe('myTableRowSelected', function(event,data) { } as mentioned before

Comment: `event.originalEvent.id` should provide the id. (see the example which I referenced)

Comment: If I understand correctly what you do then you should include [key: true](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridColumnTag) property in the definition of `eleveId`. Then the values of rowid will be the same as `eleveId`.

Comment: thanks Oleg, i retrieved the id with your example,many thanksssssssssss :) <script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('rowselect', function(event, data) {
        alert('Selected Row : ' + event.originalEvent.id);
});
</script>

<sjg:grid
        ...
        onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
        ...
>

Comment: You are welcome! I'll write the answer so that you could close the subject. Probably it will help other people.

Comment: @Oleg,i am waiting for your answer and thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it seems that `eleveId` play the role of native id your grid. If the values of the column have unique values that you could add `key="true"` property (see [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridColumnTag)) to the definition of the `eleveId` column. After that the rowid (the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements in the grid) will be the same as the values in `eleveId` column.

If the user select some row of grid the callback `onSelectRow` will be called. In [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Topics) of struts2 is described "Topics". [The example](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Example) shows how to define and subscribe the corresponding events. The value `event.originalEvent.id` in event handler will be the rowid of the last selected row. If you added `key="true"` property to the definition of the column `eleveId` then the value `event.originalEvent.id` will be the same as `eleveId`. If you can't use `key="true"` property then you can use `$("#gridtable").jqGrid("getCell", event.originalEvent.id, "eleveId")` to get the data.

Starting with version 4.3.2 jqGrid supports events additionally to callbacks. For example you can use event `jqGridSelectRow` to get full information about the last selected row:

```js
$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridSelectRow", function (e, rowid, status, orgEvent) {
    alert("rowid=" + rowid);
});
```

because you need only `rowid` then you can remove all optional parameters from the event handler

```js
$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridSelectRow", function (e, rowid) {
    alert("rowid=" + rowid);
});
```

Inside of the handler you can use `jQuery.ajax` to call struts2 action.